# display a list in reverse order from how it is listed

Tags: enumerate, pandoc

Given tex like so:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{enumerate}
```

is there a way to render this such that it appears as:

1. item C
2. item B
3. item A

(Context: I have a source file in markdown that I render to both pdf and html using pandoc.  HTML reverse listing is done via css, which renders items in the reverse of what is listed.  I'd like to do the same in the tex template.  Note this is not solved by `etarenume` since I want to change the order of the text itself relative to the source document, not simply count down.

Comment: Reversing is difficult unless storing the values before and reversing it, then typesetting it. I have no solution for markdown, but using `expl3` it is easy!

Answer (score 2):

No `pandoc` or other `markdown` solution, just prestoring the items and reversing it

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_cboettig_item_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand{\storeitems}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_cboettig_item_seq  {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\reverselist}{}{%
  \seq_reverse:N \l_cboettig_item_seq
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\displaylist}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_cboettig_item_seq {\item ##1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

% Storing
\storeitems{And,now,for,something completely, different}

\textbf{Display the original list}

\begin{enumerate}
\displaylist
\end{enumerate}

\reverselist

\textbf{Display the reversed list}

\begin{enumerate}
\displaylist
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clever, though it looks like this relies on explicitly storing the items separately.  Really hoping for a solution that could wrap around the literal LaTeX blurb.

Comment: @cboettig: Well, I am wondering whether this possible with pandoc at all...

Comment: Right, me too.  CSS has the notion of transform to reorder a list (equivalently, the use of flex boxes).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html A bit surprised there's nothing comparable in LaTeX